# Second least occurring element in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, element

I am currently working on a project and for one of the parts I need to determine the second least occurring element in a C array. In any case, the maximum number of elements in the array is going to be 100. I have a function written already to find the least occurring element:

```
int minRepeat(int arr[], int i){
    int j = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int minimum = 100;
    int minNum = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        int m = 0;
        for(l = 0; l < i; l++){
            if(arr[j] == arr[l]){
                m++;
            }
        }
        if(m < minimum){
            minimum = m;
            minNum = arr[j];
        }
    }
    return minNum;
}
```

arr[] is the inputted array and int i is the size of that array.

I am trying to create a function that will find the second least occurring element in a C array. The function is currently:

```
int secMin(int arr[], int i){
    int j = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int minimum = 0;
    int minNum = 0;

    int q = 0;
    int k = minRepeat(arr, i);
    for(q = 0; q < i; q++){
        if(arr[q] == k){
            minimum++;
        }
    }    

    int minimum2 = 100;
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        int m = 0;
        for(l = 0; l < i; l++){
            if(arr[j] == arr[l]){
                m++;
            }
        }
        if(m < minimum2){
            if(m > minimum){
                minimum2 = m;
                minNum = arr[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return minNum;
}
```

I am calling the first function to find the least occurring element. Looping through that to see how many times that element occurs in the array, and then doing the same as the first function to find the least occurring, but compare it to the first least element at the end to make sure that this element is the second least occurring.

When arr[] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1}
I get the least occurring number to be 3 and the second least occurring to be 1.
Sometimes the function works with other input and sometimes it does not, such as in the case above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just create a histogram, sort it, and pick SortedHisto[1]. Done.

Comment: @Dogbert thank you I will try to implement this

Comment: Sounds good. Also, if you need to find the `n`'th smallest/largest value in the future, or some similar metric, you don't need to add extra intermediate values.

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust your first example a little to also store the second least element:

```
if(m < minimum){
    secondminimum = minimum; 
    secondminNum = minNum
    minimum = m;
    minNum = arr[j];

}
```

Edit: I just realised that will only work if least and seconleast element do not have the same number of appearances, but you can capture that case.

Comment: But if I need to return both the least occurring element and second least occurring element, wouldn't I need them in separate functions?

Comment: do you need them as return value of your function? Otherwise return the secondleast with a function parameter